# Watir: Alternative to change the hosts file?

Tags: ruby, watir, hosts, web-testing, hosts-file

I use watir to test a test version of a website. To do so, I have to modify my [hosts-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

Is there a way to get the same result without modifying the hosts file?

The obvious idea to replace the domain with the ip-address in the calling uri does not work.

#### Background:

I define my hosts like

```
10.10.10.10 http://www.example.net/
```

Then I test:

1. I call `http://www.example.net/myapp`
2. The website redirects to a login page and I enter my credits (automated).
3. After the authorization check, the site calls again `http://www.example.net/myapp_auth`.

This call in step 3 is no relative call (a subpage of the actual domain) but a call with full url.
Without the hosts change, my test with `http://10.10.10.10/myapp` would make the authorization test in my test system (`10.10.10.10`) and then call the productive system on `http://www.example.net/`.

#### My ideas up to now (and why I don't use them):

- Use the IP in the call - This does not work, see above.
- Make my own call in the test system after my login - The URL in step 3 is dynamic defined, and it is a unwanted modification in my test sequence.
- Integrate the hosts file change in my test. - With this solution my test must run as admin to change the hosts file (I'm on Win7).

So my question: Is there a way to use watir with a kind of internal hosts file?

Comment: Sounds like things weren't really set up for a test environment. Can't you make the URLs configurable?

Comment: AFAIK I'm the first who is trying automated web testing in my company. There is no real test culture and there are too many people involved. No, in the nearer future I can't make it configurable. Maybe my tests will change the thinking of development and the site will become more testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a simple DNS server using something such as [rubydns](https://github.com/ioquatix/rubydns), add this on localhost to your DNS lookup list. If it is not there, DNS lookup should fall through (and quickly on the local loopback), if it is there, you can direct `example.net` back to localhost for all callers on your machine.